# Pie chart in highcharts is not working in ie8

Tags: internet-explorer, highcharts

I'm trying to make a pie chart using highcharts library, it is working fine in all browsers, but not in ie 8, I've spent 3 days trying to find the problem, but nothing comes out with me, please could anyone help me here?
This is my script:

```
         $(function () {
         var data = [
         {
        color: "rgb(241,241,241)",
        name: "consumed",
         innerColor:"rgb(68,197,241)",
        y: 0 
    },{
        color: "rgb(22,67,148)",
        name: "remaining",
        innerColor:"rgb(245,245,245)",
        y: 2
    }
];

var colors =[];     
var innerData = [];
var outerData = [];
var middleData = []; 

    // inner circle
    innerData.push({
        name: 'Inner Circle',
        y:data[0].y,
        color: data[0].color
    });
    // outer circle
    outerData.push({
        name: 'Outer Circle',
        y: data[0].y,
        color: data[0].innerColor
    });
     middleData.push({
        name: 'Middle Circle',
        y: data[0].y,
        color: "#ffffff"
    });
    colors.push(data[0].color);


     innerData.push({
        name: 'Inner Circle',
        y:data[1].y,
        color: data[1].color
    });
    // outer circle
    outerData.push({
        name: 'Outer Circle',
        y: data[1].y,
        color: data[1].innerColor
    });
     middleData.push({
        name: 'Middle Circle',
        y: data[1].y,
        color: "#ffffff"
    });
    colors.push(data[1].color);

    colors: Highcharts.map(colors, function(color) {
return {
    radialGradient: { cx: 0.5, cy: 0.3, r: 0.7 },
    stops: [
            [0, color],
            [1, Highcharts.Color(color).brighten(-0.3).get('rgb')] // darken
    ]
};
 })


    var my_chart={
        chart: {
            margin: [3, 0, 3, 0],
            backgroundColor: 'none',
            plotBackgroundColor: 'none',
            plotBorderWidth: 0,
            plotShadow: false,
            renderTo: 'myChart'
        },
        <?if($lang==1)
{?>
     legend:{
        useHTML:true 
    }, 
<? }?>
        title: {
        text:"<div style='font-size:20px !important;direction:ltr;color:rgb(68,197,241); '>"+con1+"   </div><div style='direction:ltr;color:rgb(22,67,148);'> "+rem1+"  </div>" ,  
        useHTML:true,
        align: 'center',
        verticalAlign: 'middle',
        y:  0
    },
        credits: {
            text: ''
        },
        plotArea: {
            shadow: null,
            borderWidth: null,
            backgroundColor: null
        },
        legend: {
            enabled: true
        },
        plotOptions: {
            pie: {
                borderWidth: 0
            }
        },
        series: [{
            type: 'pie',
            name: name,

            size: '100%',
            startAngle: -90,
            endAngle: 270,
            enableMouseTracking: false,
            innerSize: '80%',
            data: innerData,
             shadow: false,
            dataLabels: {
                enabled: false
            }
        }, 
                 {
            type: 'pie',
            name: "whiteBorder",
            size: '70%',
            innerSize: '73%',
            data: outerData,
            startAngle: -90,
            endAngle: 270,
            enableMouseTracking: false,
            shadow: false,
            dataLabels: {
                enabled: false
            }
        },{
            type: 'pie',
            name: "whiteBorder2",
            color: "#ffffff",
            startAngle: -91,
            endAngle: 480,
            size: '75%',
            innerSize: '80%',
            data: middleData,
            shadow: false,
            enableMouseTracking: false,
            dataLabels: {
                enabled: false
            }
        }]
    };

    var chart= new Highcharts.Chart(my_chart);

});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just find the answer, The problem occurs when the y value is equal to zero, when its value anything else, it works find. I'm not sure how to solve this, but in my case I checked when the value is equal to 0, I put the value to 0.001.

Comment: Maybe you have an old version of Highcharts? Try with 4.1.9?

Answer (score 2):

In highcharts.js v4.1.9, press Ctrl + F, find `this.renderer.gradients` and change this:

```
try { var b = this.renderer.gradients[this.element.gradient]; } catch (korea) { }
```

Just add `try catch`.

Comment: THIS was the correct answer!... AWESOME!... Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

That's caused by Highcharts.SVGElement.setRadialReference when failing to use unsupported gradients on IE8. You can solve the problem by ignoring the error exception being thrown, try this on page load:

```
Highcharts.SVGElement.prototype._setRadialReference = Highcharts.SVGElement.prototype.setRadialReference;
Highcharts.SVGElement.prototype.setRadialReference = function(coordinates) {
  try {
    return this._setRadialReference(coordinates);
  } catch (e) {
    return this;
  }
};
```

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

IE8 is strict markup browser, in your code you are missing ";" put semicolon in your code at

```
  colors: Highcharts.map(colors, function(color) {
return {
radialGradient: { cx: 0.5, cy: 0.3, r: 0.7 },
stops: [
        [0, color],
        [1, Highcharts.Color(color).brighten(-0.3).get('rgb')] // darken
  ]
};
 }) //you missed semicolon here put ; here
```

See this on IE [Fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/Nishith/em19cjb8/), you are not putting data properly (probably). I used dummy data and its working on IE8

Comment: I tried it, but the same, I noticed when I add the consumed value equal to the remaining value, it works, but I don't want it to work that way, I want it to display the consumed and the remaining value.

Comment: I fiddled it and it works on ie8, but when I use it in my application, it won't work. see this, it should work like this https://jsfiddle.net/em19cjb8/4/

Comment: see the console for your browser, if there any error.